# Get windows Quiet hours from Win32 or C# API

Tags: c#, c++, winapi

Windows introduced "Quiet Hours" OR "Do not disturb" feature from Windows version 8 onward. Using this feature, one can disable notifications popups for configured amount of time from task bar notification area.

I am trying to get current OS, Quiet hours within C++ or from C# application but haven't found any API or Event.

Can anybody help on this to resolve my issue?

Answer (score 4):

Since [a recent major update to Windows 10](https://www.petri.com/focus-assist-replaces-quiet-hours-in-redstone-4), "Quiet Hours" has changed to "Focus Assist" - and it seems to work differently, so previous answers don't apply any more.

The only solution I could find for this so far, is [the one offered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53411482/997940).

Answer (score 2):

There is a registry value set to 0 during quiet hours named "NOC_GLOBAL_SETTINGS_TOASTS_ENABLED". Here is working code to determine if a user currently has quiet hours enabled:

```
public static bool IsQuietHours()
{
    string path = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Notifications\\Settings";
    string key = "NOC_GLOBAL_SETTING_TOASTS_ENABLED";
    int? toastsEnabled = (int?)Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(path, key, 1);
    return (toastsEnabled == 0);
}
```

Comment: Since a recent update to Windows 10, the quiet hours has changed (not just renamed) to "focus assist" and this solution doesn't seem to work any more :(

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the original answer from @PhilWilliams, albeit it being link only answer, was correct:

You can query the state by using [`SHQueryUserNotificationState()` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762242(v=vs.85).aspx). See also [`QUERY_USER_NOTIFICATION_STATE` enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762533(v=vs.85).aspx) for possible value.

Comment: I tried for getting current state of the Notifications whether it is ON or OFF using SHQueryUserNotificationState API. But it always returns QUNS_ACCEPTS_NOTIFICATIONS even when all notifications are disabled. Tried this in C# Application.

Comment: Actually it returns QUNS_APP when I change notification settings within windows 8 metro mode/store mode i.e. from  PC Settings > Search and Apps > Notifications > Show app notifications. This means Windows Store app is running and nothing actual Notification ON/OFF value.

Comment: Since a recent update to Windows 10, the quiet hours has changed (not just renamed) to "focus assist" and this solution doesn't seem to work any more :(